# Find Emails in string with PerlRegex in Delphi

Tags: regex, perl, delphi

I'm using regular expressions in Delphi with PerlRegex component, I have a regular expression perl perl works perfect, but when used in Delphi with PerlRegex component finds nothing

Code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, PerlRegex;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  code: string;
  regex: TPerlRegEx;
begin
  code := 'sdaasd saassd test@hotmail.com sdasdsd test2@gmail.com sdsadsd asdasdasd';

  regex := TPerlRegEx.Create();

  regex.regex := 'qr/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+\@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/i';
  regex.Subject := code;

  while regex.MatchAgain do
  begin
    ShowMessage(regex.Groups[1]);
  end;
end;

end.
```

As I can recover mails with PerlRegex?

Comment: What kind of email do you want to match? Only "standard" email address or every *valid* email ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qr/.../i` is part of the Perl *language*, not just regex syntax. So this line

```
regex.regex := 'qr/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+\@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/i';
```

is wrong, and should be

```
regex.RegEx   := '[A-Z0-9._%+-]+\@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}';
regex.Options := [preCaseLess];
```